# How to display TestConnection -Quiet result in PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, shell, powershell-cmdlet

`Get-CIMInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer | Select-Object Name, @{label="IPAddress";expression={($_.comment | Select-string -Pattern "\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}" -AllMatches).Matches.value}}, @{label="Status";expression={ForEach-Object{Test-Connection -ComputerName '{0}' $_.IPAddress -Count 1 -Quiet}}}`

The above code gives me the following o/p:

```
Name                          IPAddress       Status
----                          ---------       ------
Webex Document Loader         100.100.100.100
OneNote (Desktop)             111.111.111.111
Microsoft XPS Document Writer 120.120.120.120
Microsoft Print to PDF        123.123.123.123
Fax                           8.8.8.8
```

When the `ForEach-Object{Test-Connection -ComputerName $IPAddress -Count 1 -Quiet}` is run separately, I get the following o/p:

```
False
False
False
False
True
```

What I need is:

```
Name                          IPAddress       Status
----                          ---------       ------
Webex Document Loader         100.100.100.100 False
OneNote (Desktop)             111.111.111.111 False
Microsoft XPS Document Writer 120.120.120.120 False
Microsoft Print to PDF        123.123.123.123 False
Fax                           8.8.8.8         True
```

How can I achieve this, in a single cmdlet (pipelined) ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the `ForEach-Object` statement in the property expression for `Status`: `@{label="Status";expression={Test-Connection -ComputerName '{0}' $_.IPAddress -Count 1 -Quiet}}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Tried, but did no good. The o/p still remains the same (empty 'Status' column)

Comment: Ahh, I see, you're calculating the `IPAddress` value in the same step, so that won't work.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes. Any alternate way to achieve the targeted o/p ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `ForEach-Object{}` statement from the property expression, and then split it into two `Select-Object` calls - the first one will calculate the `IPAddress` property value, which the second one can then use for the `Status` calculation:

```
Get-CIMInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer | Select-Object Name, @{label="IPAddress";expression={($_.comment | Select-string -Pattern "\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}" -AllMatches).Matches.value}} |Select Name,IPAddress,@{label="Status";expression={Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.IPAddress -Count 1 -Quiet}}
```